# Jetty Split File Server combined with a Header Filter

Tags: servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

This Jetty doco page https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedded-examples.html#embedded-split-file-server shows how to set up two context handlers which serve two different resource bases (eg. /var/www/docs and /var/www/api-docs) to the same path (eg. myurl.com/documentation).

A previous question showed how to do this with a ServletContextHandler: [Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty). You can add a Filter to a ServletContextHandler, but how do you add a Filter to a ContextHandlerCollection? For example an X-Frame-Options header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom `HandlerWrapper` and wrap the other `Handlers` you want to act on.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217143/775715