# Jetty Prometheus Java client Error StatisticsHandler has no Wrapped Handler

Tags: java, jetty, prometheus

I am following the Prometheus Java client library to expose metrics of my Jetty server. From [here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/cb0c862ca52231e6369ef4d9e1ef5b9178e763e6/simpleclient_jetty/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/jetty/JettyStatisticsCollector.java#L21) . But when I start the server I get the error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start jetty server
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StatisticsHandler has no Wrapped Handler
```

To fix this I had to do -

```
    StatisticsHandler stats = new StatisticsHandler();
    stats.setServer(server.getServer());
    HandlerWrapper hw = new HandlerWrapper();
    stats.setHandler(hw);
    new JettyStatisticsCollector(stats).register();

    contextCollectionHandler.addHandler(stats);
    server.setHandler(contextCollectionHandler);

    try {
        server.start();
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to start jetty server", e);
    }
```

But, I dont see the stats incrementing, when I make requests to my server through Postman. I get responses, 200, 404 etc. But none of the stats such as `jetty_requests_total` or `jetty_responses_total` are incrementing. They stay at 0. The only thing that changes is `jetty_stats_seconds`. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`ContextHandlerCollection` can only hold/use/process `ContextHandler` based handlers.

Your `StatisticsHandler` and `Handler.Wrapper` are not `ContextHandler` implementations, they will never be called.

The Handler tree is just that, a tree.  Think of it like that and it will start to make sense.

See past answer

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217143/775715

If you look at `StatisticsHandler` you'll find that it's a `HandlerWrapper` implementation.

See: [Javadoc for `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler` in Jetty 11.0.11](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/11.0.11/org.eclipse.jetty.server/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/StatisticsHandler.html)

In short, you want that `StatisticsHandler` to be somewhere early in your Handler tree, and have it wrap whatever handlers you want it to operate on.

Something like this ...

```
Server.setHandler
  HandlerList
    StatisticsHandler
      GzipHandler
        ContextHandlerCollection
          ContextHandler("/")
          ServletContextHandler("/rest")
          WebAppContext("/app")
    DefaultHandler
```